# Calling a member pointer to function that points to a C function within a windows procedure make app crash

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, pointer-to-member, wndproc

**I have this main.cpp code:**

```C++
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void click(){printf("button clicked\n");}

struct WindowData
{
    void (*PF)();        

    WindowData():PF(NULL){}
};

LRESULT CALLBACK dialog_procedure(HWND h,UINT u,WPARAM w,LPARAM l)
{
    WindowData *wp=(WindowData*)GetWindowLongPtr(h,GWL_USERDATA);

    switch(u)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if(LOWORD(w)==BN_CLICKED)
            if(wp && wp->PF)wp->PF();
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(h,u,w,l);
}

int main()
{

    WindowData * windowdata=new WindowData();

    windowdata->PF=click; //bind function

    HWND window=CreateWindow(WC_DIALOG,"App",WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,0,0,300,300,0,0,0,windowdata);
    HWND button=CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON,"Click",WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,0,0,100,30,0,0,0,0);

    SetWindowLongPtr(window,GWL_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)dialog_procedure);



    MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0)>0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 1;

}
```

**Now i build all with: c++ main.cpp -lcomctl32**

**Run the executable**

but when i press the "Click" button, PF is never called...

calling windowdata->PF() after binding, works;

calling click() anywhere in dialog_procedure works;

calling wp->PF() anywhere in dialog_procedure make app crash;

**where am I wrong?**

Comment: This is missing in your code `SetWindowLongPtr(window,GWL_USERDATA,(LONG_PTR)windowdata);`

Comment: Very Thanks!!! :)     the last member of createstruct works only in WM_CREATE message with CREATESTRUCT and blablabla....

Comment: @AlexFarber: You should write that as an answer, so that freesoft can accept it, rather than editing the title to *RESOLVED*

Comment: You also forgot to forward unhandled messages to the original window procedure. Actually, why aren't you just using CreateDialpg in the first place? Why manually create a WC_DIALOG and then throw away its window procedure? (You now have a memory leak since the original window procedure no longer gets a change to clean up.)

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to `main` function:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(window,GWL_USERDATA,(LONG_PTR)windowdata);
```